# Running nbdiff-web from a Docker container

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, dockerfile

I'm trying to use nbdime's `nbdiff-web` from a docker container. When I run

```
$ nbdiff-web 5e035626bac76eba78548157ddf9dd3fac8cfd5f 40d4652fff52743ca445034876446cc0933d5f24
```

I get back

```
[I nbdimeserver:375] Listening on 127.0.0.1, port 39843
[W webutil:18] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
[I webutil:29] URL: http://127.0.0.1:39843/difftool
```

Obviously, I can't access the URL because on my Dockerfile I'm not exposing that port.

Dockerfile

```
FROM jupyter/scipy-notebook

USER root

# Copy the git config file
COPY gitconfig /home/jovyan/.gitconfig

# bash instead of dash to use source
RUN ln -snf /bin/bash /bin/sh

# These require sudo so they must come before defining
# a user
RUN sudo apt-get update

# Install ssh
RUN sudo apt-get -y install openssh-server
RUN sudo apt-get -y install curl

# Install the tree command
RUN sudo apt-get install tree

USER jovyan

# Install additional python packages
RUN pip install --upgrade pip \
 && pip install autopep8 \
 && pip install gspread \
 && pip install isort \
 && pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions \
 && pip install nbimporter \
 && pip install nbdime \
 && pip install oauth2client \
 && pip install pathlib \
 && pip install selenium \
 && nbdime extensions --enable

RUN jupyter contrib nbextension install --user

# Enable Jupyter extensions by default
RUN jupyter nbextension enable autosavetime/main \
 && jupyter nbextension enable jupyter-autopep8-master/jupyter-autopep8 \
 && jupyter nbextension enable codefolding/edit \
 && jupyter nbextension enable code_prettify/isort \
 && jupyter nbextension enable scratchpad/main \
 && jupyter nbextension enable splitcell/splitcell \
 && jupyter nbextension enable table_beautifier/main \
 && jupyter nbextension enable code_prettify/2to3 \
 && jupyter nbextension enable init_cell/main \
 && jupyter nbextension enable nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main \
 && jupyter nbextension enable spellchecker/main \
 && jupyter nbextension enable toc2/main \
 && jupyter nbextension enable toggle_all_line_numbers/main \
 && jupyter nbextension enable varInspector/main

# Enable nbdime by default
RUN nbdime config-git --enable --global

# Create two dirs to mount volumes
RUN cd /home/jovyan && rm -rf work && mkdir dev && mkdir filestream
```

I also don't know which port `nbdiff-web` will launch on which makes it harder to pick a port to EXPOSE in the Dockerfile (for that, I tried using the solution [here](https://github.com/jupyter/nbdime/issues/207) but got an authorisation error back).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while, but for anyone interested, I faced the same issue and setting the IP flag to `0.0.0.0` fixed it for me:

```
nbbdiff-web -p 3000 --ip 0.0.0.0
```

This is the repo from where I got the idea: https://github.com/trallard/JNB_reproducible/blob/b7d400f2145b2e2886de465a6983e0e172dac002/bash_aliases